# RoR - rspec tests failing and shouldn't

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, rspec

I'm running these rspec tests for my controller:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe MoviesController do
  describe 'searching for similar movies' do
    before :each do 
      @fake_movies = [mock('Movie'), mock('Movie')]
      @fake_movie = FactoryGirl.build(:movie, :id => "1", :title => "Star Wars", :director => "George Lucas") 
    end
    it 'should follow the route to the similar movies by director page' do
      assert_routing('movies/1/similar', {:controller => 'movies', :action => 'similar', :id => '1'}) 
    end

    it 'should find the similar movies by director' do
      Movie.should_receive(:find_by_id).with("1").and_return(@fake_movie)
      Movie.should_receive(:find_by_director).with(@fake_movie.director).and_return(@fake_movies)
      get :similar, {:id => "1"}
    end

    it 'should select the Similiar Movies template for rendering' do
      Movie.should_receive(:find_by_id).with("1").and_return(@fake_movie)
      Movie.should_receive(:find_by_director).with(@fake_movie.director).and_return(@fake_movies)
      get :similar, {:id => "1"}
      response.should render_template('similar')
    end

    it 'it should make the results available to the template' do
      Movie.should_receive(:find_by_id).with("1").and_return(@fake_movie)
      Movie.should_receive(:find_by_director).with(@fake_movie.director).and_return(@fake_movies)
      get :similar, {:id => "1"}
      assigns(:movies).should == @fake_results
    end
  end
end
```

Buy they are failing with this output:

```
    Failures:

  1) MoviesController searching for similar movies should find the similar movies by director
     Failure/Error: get :similar, {:id => "1"}
       <Movie(id: integer, title: string, rating: string, description: text, release_date: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, director: string) (class)> received :find_by_director with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("George Lucas")
              got: ()
     # ./app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:62:in `similar'
     # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:17:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) MoviesController searching for similar movies should select the Similiar Movies template for rendering
     Failure/Error: get :similar, {:id => "1"}
       <Movie(id: integer, title: string, rating: string, description: text, release_date: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, director: string) (class)> received :find_by_director with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("George Lucas")
              got: ()
     # ./app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:62:in `similar'
     # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:23:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  3) MoviesController searching for similar movies it should make the results available to the template
     Failure/Error: get :similar, {:id => "1"}
       <Movie(id: integer, title: string, rating: string, description: text, release_date: datetime, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, director: string) (class)> received :find_by_director with unexpected arguments
         expected: ("George Lucas")
              got: ()
     # ./app/controllers/movies_controller.rb:62:in `similar'
     # ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:30:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.15517 seconds
4 examples, 3 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:14 # MoviesController searching for similar movies should find the similar movies by director
rspec ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:20 # MoviesController searching for similar movies should select the Similiar Movies template for rendering
rspec ./spec/controllers/movies_controller_spec.rb:27 # MoviesController searching for similar movies it should make the results available to the template
```

When this is my controller method:

```
def similar 
    @movies = Movie.find_by_director(Movie.find_by_id(params[:id]))
  end
```

I do not understand why these tests are failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was I was calling the wrong method. `find_by_director` isn't the method that was supposed to be used, but `find_all_by_director`, hence what was going to the method was wrong.

Comment: did you change `find_by_director` to `find_all_by_director` in both your tests and controller? Or just one or the other? Curious because I'm currently taking the course

Comment: Yes, in both, find_by_director doesn't exist it seems.

Comment: In both the controller and test I changed every find_by to find_all and still no luck. Was there a model method that you also implemented?

Comment: Nope, no extra implementation, it's default Rails

Answer (score 0):

You need to first give the request with proper method and then test for the expected result.

Place the below line in the beginning of the failed examples.

```
get :similar, {:id => "1"}
```

Like below.

```
it 'should find the similar movies by director' do
  get :similar, {:id => "1"}
  Movie.should_receive(:find_by_id).with("1").and_return(@fake_movie)
  Movie.should_receive(:find_by_director).with(@fake_movie.director).and_return(@fake_movies)
end
```

Comment: This is not how rspec works, first you set up what you expect in the call and then you execute said call

Comment: Friend I think you are little bit confused with Mock.Movie.should_receive(:find_by_id).with("1").and_return(@fake_movie) !=  Mock(Movie, :find_by_id => @fake_movie)

Comment: I never thought them to be the same at all

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to get rid of mocking and work with "real" objects that persist in DB:

```
describe MoviesController do
  describe 'searching for similar movies' do
    before do 
      @movie = FactoryGirl.create(:movie,
        :title => "Star Wars",
        :director => "George Lucas") 

      @another_lucas_movie = FactoryGirl.create(:movie,
        :title => "Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade",
        :director => "George Lucas")
    end

    it 'should find the similar movies by director' do
      get :similar, {:id => @movie.id}
      assigns(:movies).should include @another_lucas_movie
    end
  end
end
```

See [RSpec docs](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/) for more details.

Comment: @8vius That's in theory, but in practice mocked tests keep passing even if your code actually fails after some changes were made. You should keep it in mind.

Comment: Alright I will, also this is a homework assignment from the Stanford SaaS course, so I'm trying to use everything they teach and this is the way they're doing it. Any idea why my tests fail?

Answer (score 0):

Use `FactoryGirl.create` instead of `FactoryGirl.build`

`.build` acts as `Model.new` You have to save your test records to database.